SQL Server's ORIGINAL_LOGIN() returns incorrect user name (AD vs local account)
I'm trying to switch between user contexts but ORIGINAL_LOGIN() returns some magic AD account rather than the local machine account I connected with. This makes it impossible to switch back to the original caller context. I'm connecting as a local Windows user.
SELECT ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), SYSTEM_USER


MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com | localMachine\localUser

The login I connected with is indeed localMachine\localUser. I'm not even sure where the MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com account comes from, Windows sort of invented this on its own.
Now consider this sproc:
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE spTest WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER AS
BEGIN
    -- Do high-privilege things ...

    EXECUTE AS LOGIN = ORIGINAL_LOGIN(); -- Fails!
    -- Impersonate caller, check some permissions
    REVERT;

    -- Do more high-privilege things ...
END
GO

EXEC spTest;

The EXECUTE AS LOGIN impersonation invariably fails with

Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com', error code 0x54b.

Obviously, since MicrosoftAccount\name@email.com is not used or configured anywhere. This makes ORIGINAL_LOGIN() completely useless to us, and I have no idea how to temporarily switch back to the caller context. Note that the code above is for demonstration only, the actual code base is significantly more complex with chains of sproc calls and triggers involved.
TLDR: How can I get ORIGINAL_LOGIN() to return the actual original login?

Why not use execute as caller? And why are you still trying to make this silly solution work (i remember your last question :))

Are you using Azure/Entra AD?

@siggemannen Because, as mentioned, this is called from a long chain of elevated code. I need the original caller. Why is this a silly solution?

@Charlieface Not exactly, or at least not on purpose. But new Windows really tries hard to tie you to the Azure/Entra AD framework whether you like it or not.

Because you should avoid execute as owner and use certificates etc if you want to make privileged calls. Btw, does: exec xp_logininfo returns anything "interesting" for that user?

@siggemannen No, exec xp_logininfo only exposes localMachine\localUser, there is nothing to tie it to the Azure/Entra AD account. I'd also like to point out that the solution works fine when there is no Azure/Entra AD involved. If possible I'd like to completely disable the Azure/Entra AD feature for SQL Server, I don't even know why SQL Server chooses it over localMachine\localUser.
